# Composite Words in Lucene

Tags: lucene

is it possible that give a list of Composite Words to lucene for text indexing ?

for example, i want indexing "Computer Information" as a single Word.

i can do it with convert "Computer Information" to "Computer_Information" or "ComputerInformation", but  this converting is very difficult, the problem is Open here :

[Replace Long list Words in a big Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620238/replace-long-list-words-in-a-big-text-file)

Comment: This is possible with a TokenFilter which would keep into memory the last processed tokens, but you need to be aware that this kind of tokens would not work with the standard Lucene query parser, since it first splits on whitespace before analyzing. Can you describe what your goal is, maybe other approaches would work as well.

Comment: it is for a Information Retrieval Research(ESA Method) and difficult to explain, but can found more information here : http://github.com/faraday/wikiprep-esa - my supposition is that Indexing "Computer_Information" can better Result in query time.

Comment: i googling TokenFilter , but don't understand how use it for my goal, my composite words list has ~12 million entry ! is it faster than replace composite Words with single Words(A B) to (A_B)

Comment: What is your real intention? why do you want `indexing "Computer Information" as a single Word.`

Comment: in ESA (two comment latter), for every Term(Word), you have a vector.  for a long text, you must aggregate vectors, but result not very good. a reason is  number of vectors. my idea is that create a vector for composite Words ( in this implementation github.com/faraday/wikiprep-esa   use lucene for create vectors)

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a](https://gist.github.com/1253934) token filter to do this, which you can use. It's what @jpountz was describing.

Comment: Very Nice, do it have good performance? my Dictionary have ~3 million entry

Comment: It has whatever performance the underlying Hash table implementation has. You might want to persist your analyzer since creating a hash table with 3m entries will take a while.